# Process img from url using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

How can i process image from url ?
I am opening image from specific url and trying to process it .

```
    import PIL
    from PIL import ImageFont
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageDraw
    url="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png"
    img = Image.open(url)
    -----
    ---Lines of code-- 
    -----
```

This giving me error : `IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename`

Whats wrong i am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit more convoluted than that. First you need to download the data using `urllib`. Then you store that data in a `StringIO` object. Then finally you `open` from that object in PIL:

```
import urllib
import StringIO
imgdata = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imgdata))
```